# How to hover a div and make its background-image slowly dissapear without affecting the content that's inside it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with a background-color , background-image and some text on it . I want , when i hover the div , the background-image to slowly dissapear, like a transition effect or something, but the text and the color still remain there visible in the div.I am open to any type of method.

[image: This is how the div should look before hover]

[image: This is how it's supposed to be while hovering]

Comment: Share your current code please.

Comment: What have you tried? What has or hasn't worked? What's your HTML and code look like? At a guess, you'll want to change the background opacity. With the lack of code, you may get some serious downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using only CSS adding a few DOM elements.

```css
.fadebg {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.fadebg:hover .img, .fadebg:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Screenshot_Snarf.jpg);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}

.img, img {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 1s all;
  -moz-transition: 1s all;
  -ms-transition: 1s all;
  -o-transition: 1s all;
  transition: 1s all;
}
```

```html
<div class="fadebg">
    <div class="text">Hi</div>
    <div class="img"></div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="fadebg">
    <div class="text">Hi</div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Screenshot_Snarf.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: This is really useful. Thanks a lot ! :D

Comment: You're welcome. I also added an example for using an image tag instead of the img css class.